# Assigning one struct variable to the another varible of a same type which is in different struct in C++

Tags: c++

Can we assign one variable from a structure to another variable of a same type which is in a different struct, directly in C++? Such as:

```
struct Test1 
{
   inx x1;
   int y1;
}

struct Test2
{
   int x2;
   int y2;
}

void trialStruct(Test2& origin2)
{
   Test1 origin1;
   origin1.x1 = origin2.x2;
   origin2.y1 = origin2.y2
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Is there anything that makes you think you couldn't?

Comment: BTW: You really want to make a copy by passing the struct? So you should use a reference. And naming your function try looks mysterious as try is a keyword in c++. Why you did not check your code with a debugger?

Comment: With the exception that you can't name a function `try` (and the typo in `inx`) it's all fine and well.

Comment: This is explained in any beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: As mentioned before: yes. You can do this, but this isn't the most efficient way of doing it.
You could just as easily create an overloaded constructor for Test1 like `Test1(const Test2& org): x1(org.x2), y1(org.y2) {}`

Comment: @churil Someone said that this wouldn't work without casting because struct types are different. That's why I wanted to be sure

Comment: Change your try function to `void try_it(Test2& origin2)`   and try your self.

Comment: @GünkutAğabeyoğlu Casting these structs to one another is theoretically possible, because they have the same data structure. It'd be easy enough to just `memcpy` them over one another

Comment: Casting and memcpy to data of different structs should be avoided at all. If it is the same type, you can directly assign if it is not the same type, don't cast nor memcpy even if the layout is the self. Latest in the moment during program maintenance of a prog this will be a hard to find bug. BTW: it is UB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we assign one variable from a structure to another variable of a same type which is in a different struct, directly in C++?

Yes, the type of `origin1.x1` and `origin2.x2` is same(both are `int`) and we can *assign* `origin2.x2` to `origin1.x1` as you've done in your example.

---

Note also that instead of *assigning* individual members, you can use **aggregate initialization** to *initialize* the data member in your particular example as shown below:

```
void trialStruct(Test2& origin2)
{
   //aggregate initialization 
   Test1 origin1{origin2.x2, origin2.y2};
}
```